# Given a set of number, how do you permute a pair of numbers?

Tags: java, permutation

I've tried to Google this question but I can't seem to find results to from a data set get a permutation of a pair of numbers. (java) For example given

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

how and is it possible, to get permutations like

```
1,2
```

then

```
2,3
```

I'm not asking for the possibilities.

**EDIT:**

Another example give

```
1 2 3
```

I'm asking for a way to be able to get

```
1,2
2,1
2,3
3,2
3,1
1,3
```

and so on.

Comment: Google ain't going to do programming for us. What have you tried?

Comment: You could do it with a nested loop, if you want to.

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you need permutations (that is "reorderings") or subsets of your given numbers/strings? Do you need all there are or just some of them?

Comment: @piet.t All there are

Comment: Please have a look at [this link](http://www.freewebs.com/permute/soda_submit.html). Hope it answers your query :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw i think the code is overall helpful, but its not too useful since its not in java and i have no clue how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't compile the code but I think this solves your problem

```
    public void function(){
    int [] dataSet = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    ArrayList<ArrayList <int> > result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i<dataSet.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<dataSet.length;j++){
            if(i == j)
                continue;
            ArrayList<int> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
            tmp.add(dataSet[i]);
            tmp.add(dataSet[j]);
            result.add(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This really helps! THANKS, what I had in mind was much more complicated.